# animateWithDuration not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to animate a view with some buttons and controllers for my main view into the screen from the right side of the screen. The problem is it doesn't animate, it just goes directly to the finished state.

This is my code:

```
UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
options = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OptionsView"];
options.delegate = self;        
[self.view addSubview:options.view];
options.view.center = CGPointMake(floor(total_width+options.view.frame.size.width/2)+10, floor(total_height/2));

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     options.view.center = CGPointMake(floor(total_width-options.view.frame.size.width/2)+10, floor(total_height/2));
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

EDIT

To make things more strange, if I put this animation inside the completion block of another animation then this one works, but not the new one.

```
    UIButton* boton = (UIButton*) sender;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         boton.alpha = 0.0;

                         //Jumps directly to 0, animation doesn't work

                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                          animations:^{
                                              options.view.center = CGPointMake(floor(total_width-options.view.frame.size.width/2)+10, floor(total_height/2));

                                              //It works now, but it doesn't take 5 seconds to start, it starts right away

                                          } 
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                              NSLog(@"Done!");
                                          }]; 

                     }];
```

Answer (score 3):

The line before the `animateWithDuration:...` call directly assigns the `center` to the same value that you're animating to. Either remove that or assign the initial `center` value there. An animation that has the same start and end values obviously has no effect.

Comment: I thought that too at first but there's a '+' in the start position, & a '-' in the end position

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that, sorry. Perhaps both expressions evaluate to `0`, so there's no difference?

Comment: No, both expressions evalutate correctly. The first time I assign the center it sets it outside of the screen. The second time it moves it just to the left of the right border, as expected. But with no animation